# Создание рукописного шрифта

Tags: шрифты

Существуют много онлайн-сервисов для создания рукописных шрифтов, но почти все либо платные, либо криво работают (нормально не распознают заполненую форму). Есть ли сервис, который бесплатно создает шрифт из распечатаной/заполненой формы?

Нужна именно программа, которая позволяет распечатать форму, которая заполняется вручную, сканируется, а скан распознаётся программой и выдаётся шрифт.

Например [myscriptfont.com](http://www.myscriptfont.com/)

Comment: Может быть [эта статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127088/) вам пригодиться. Там же указана [программа](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html), с помощью которой и создавать шрифт. Эту же программку, можно найти не только на официальном сайте ;)

Answer (score 1):

Немного офтоп, но может пригодиться. Есть у google [сервис с бесплатной базой шрифтов](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

Comment: Нужно именно свой шрифт сделать, но спасибо, пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

В своем компе нажми "выполнить", введи "Eudcedit". Откроется программа для редактирования шрифтов, любой шрифт можно вытащить или сохранить.

Либо такие варианты:

1. Скачать программу "Font Creator Program" и баловаться в ней.
2. Или же "FontLab"

"FontLab" - получше. [Ссылка на версию 4.52.](http://www.pchome.de/download/fontlab-v4.52_1692.html)

Если ссылка не будет работать - Гоша в помощь.

Comment: Попробую сделать, но суть вопроса слегка в другом.

Нужно именно сделать шрифт вручную, тоесть нужна программа, которая позволяет распечатать форму, которая заполняется вручную, сканируется, а скан распознаётся программой и выдаётся шрифт.

Comment: Гм так этого в вопросе не было. Тут целый комплекс программ нужен... Куда более сложно, чем создать шрифт.

Кстати программа для сканирования фото и вывода текстовой информации в файл называется abby fine reader.

Comment: Извините, плохо описал.

Почему комплекс програм? Есть ведь программы/сервисы, которые ``якобы`` делают это за $9.99.

----

Abby Fine Reader — знаю, эта программа вообще не при чем здесь.